# Rspec test with mock for a static method and non static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I have a method like this:

```
def self.method
  #API CALL
end
```

And I was writing a test for the controller method that calls this static method. It is like this:

```
it 'update order to confirmed' do
    Order.should_receive(:process_payment).and_return({})
    sign_in user
    attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, :valid_order)
    patch :confirm_order, params: { id: order.id, order: attributes }
    order.reload
    expect(order.confirmed).to eq true
end
```

And it was working fine. But I had to make this method not static, and the test starts to fail.

In my controller, I am calling the method like this now:

```
Order.new.process_payment(@order)
```

The problem is with my mock I guess, but I cannot see how to solve it. Any ideas on how I can adapt my mock to this new format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `allow_any_instance_of` method:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Order).to receive(:process_payment).and_return({})
```

Comment: `allow_any_instance_of` [is deprecated](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance) and should be replaced by `allow`. [Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/basics/allowing-messages) are some examples

Answer (score 0):

Igor's answer works fine. I've also managed to make it work like this:

```
Order.any_instance.should_receive(:process_payment).and_return({})
```

Comment: As a heads up, this is the old syntax using `Object.any_instace` vs the modern `allow_any_instance_of`. Here's the documentation: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/old-syntax/any-instance